# Change Google Chrome about:blank favicon

Tags: google-chrome, favicon

I have a very strange favicon showing up in Google Chrome on the about:blank page:

[image: about:blank favicon]

How can I change this back to the normal blank document favicon?

I'm on Mac OSX, and have had this problem on both 10.9 and 10.10. I tried removing Chrome and reinstalling it to no avail.